# Spring Boot Mongo @Query syntax

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have this query which isn't working and I've tried looking for material to better understand the syntax behind it, but I'm not having much luck. If someone could point out some resources for me to look into, I would appreciate it. Specifically, I'm having trouble with `ISODate(:#{#start})` and what roles the `:#` or `{#parameter}` play in this query.

Also, if you happen to know how to fix this up. Please share!

**Edit** The dates in the db should be engulfed by the date parameters supplied. I originally had `'foo': :#{#parameter}` which worked for looking up values, but here I've had to wrap the string with `ISODate()` in order to convert it for comparison.

```java
@Query("
   { 'user.id': :#{#id} },
   { 'date.events.start': { $gte: ISODate(:#{#start}) } },
   { 'date.events.end': { $lte: ISODate(:#{#currentDate}) } }
")
List<Case> getUsersInPeriod(@Param("id") String id, 
   @Param("start") String start, @Param("currentDate") String currentDate);
```

**Edit** Playing around in Mongo Compass query box with the following:

```java
{'user.id': '5df2b19006f31c190cc13288' }, { 'date.events.start': {$gte: ISODate('2020-02-13')} }, {'date.events.end': {$lte: ISODate('2020-02-31')}}
```

and it does not work as expected. So I am not sure what the issue is.

Sample Mongo document values:

```
start: "2020-01-20T08:30:00.000-06:00" (String)
end: "2020-01-20T15:30:00.000-06:00" (String)
```

Sample Comparison values:

```
start: "2020-01-16" (String)
end: "2020-01-31" (String)
```

Which didn't work, and so I wrapped the comparison values with `ISODate()` and that still didn't work, which now has me looking at document string values.

**Edit: #3**
I've converted some values in the document to Date and changed the query in Mongo Compass to:

```
{$and: [{'user.id': '5df2b19006f31c190cc13288' }, { 'date.events.start': {$gte: ISODate('2020-01-21')} }, {'date.events.end': {$lte: ISODate('2020-01-31')}}]}
```

which only picks up the document values formed as `Date` instead of `String`... so, I think I narrowed down the problem to two things (My original issue still persists with the syntax).

**How do I deal with Mongo documents with string dates?** Is it possible to parse the document string dates as ISODate while doing the query? 
@prasad_ answer to formatting: *can parse `String` or `Date`, but both must be of the same type. Ideally `Date` is used.*

**Edit #4: What I know so far...**
`User.id` checks out. There's no issue there. I know the `$and` usage is correct. 
Sample Document entries:

```java
start: "2020-01-20T08:30:00.000-06:00" (String)
```

```
end: "2020-01-20T15:30:00.000-06:00" (String)
```

The above values should be engulfed by the following parameters:

```
start: 2020-01-16T19:57:54.949-06:00
```

```
end: 2020-01-31T23:59:59.999-06:00
```

I've converted both sets of strings to `String` or to `Date` and neither has returned results from the query made in my application; however ...

MongoDB Compass Community Query filter:
`{'$and':[{'user.id':'5df2b19006f31c190cc13288'},{'date.events.start':{'$gte':'2020-01-22T08:30:00.000-06:00'}},{'date.events.end':{'$lte':'2020-01-31T15:30:00.000-06:00'}}]}`

Does filter strings correctly, and...

`{'$and':[{'user.id':'5df2b19006f31c190cc13288'},{'date.events.start':{'$gte':'2020-01-22T08:30:00.000-06:00'}},{'date.events.end':{'$lte':'2020-01-31T15:30:00.000-06:00'}}]}`
Works when the document fields are of type `Date` and

```
start: 2020-01-21T14:30:00.000+00:00 (Date)
```

```
end: 2020-01-21T21:30:00.000+00:00 (Date)
```

Since I can get results in Mongo Compass Community, there must be something wrong with my application's query here:

```java
@Query("{'$and': [{ 'user.id': :#{#id} }, { 'date.events.start': { '$gte': :#{#startPeriod} } }, { 'date.events.end': { '$lte': :#{#currentDate} } } ]}")
    List<Case> getUsersInPeriod(@Param("id") String id, @Param("startPeriod") String startPeriod, @Param("currentDate") String currentDate);
```

The document entry is structured as:

```
date: (Object)
    events: (Array)
        [0]: (Object)
            start: (String)
            end: (String)
        [1]: (Object)
            (...)
        (...)
```

**Solution**
I was able to find something that put me on the right path:

> Internally, MongoDB can store dates as either Strings or as 64-bit integers. If you intend to do any operations using the MongoDB query or aggregate functions, or if you want to index your data by date, you'll likely want to store your dates as integers. If you're using the built-in "Date" data type, or a date wrapped in the ISODate() function, you're also storing your date as an integer.

https://www.compose.com/articles/understanding-dates-in-compose-mongodb/

So I changed everything to Date and now it's working as expected. Not sure what I had done wrong the first time I checked `Date` types, but oh well.

I still don't understand the syntax I originally asked, so if someone wants to help by providing something to read, please and thank you.

Comment: Please post a sample input document showing the start and end date fields.

Comment: For the date comparison, try replacing the  `'date.events.start': { $gte: ISODate('2020-02-13') }` _with this:_ `'date.events.start': { $gte: '2020-02-13' }`.

Comment: Will this work with only strings? I was under the impression that the values in the documents and the comparison values in the query needed to both be type `Date` in order to evaluate `$gte` & `$lte`.

I'm not able to test anything out until I better understand the syntax here. I'm not convinced I have it right: `ISODate(:#{#start})`, more specifically, parameter substitution with `:#{#parameter}`

Comment: as I've shown above, I have the application query, and then the in-application Mongo Compass Community Query field...which has shown that evaluating by `$gte` & `$lte` on strings hasn't worked. If you look at what I posted again, start from ***Edit #3*** you'll see that I have gotten results in the Mongo Compass Community with those changes.

Comment: _"Will this work with only strings? ..."_ Yes, date values can be strings. Often these are stored by applications in the database as strings. You can compare string dates. But, the string date values need to be of the same format year(yyyy)-month(mm)-day(dd). _Ideally_, the date fields should be of type `Date`. Finally, the comparison (equal, greater or lesser) should be between the same type.

Comment: Your previous comment was very helpful, @prasad_ 
I went back and double-checked my strings and made sure they were the same formats. 
It seems they were already of the same format in ***parameters***
start: `2020-01-16T19:49:17.911-06:00` & end: `2020-01-31T23:59:59.999-06:00`
***document***
start: `2020-01-20T08:30:00.000-06:00`
end: `2020-01-20T15:30:00.000-06:00`

Yet, I still do not get any results from the query. Any other ideas?